# Android app that only displays the pictures within a particular folder

Tags: gratis, android, offline, image-viewer, gallery

I sometimes need to show my artwork to people I just met.

Pictures of my artwork are in a specific folder /sdcard/portfolio on my Android phone.

However, launching the stock Gallery app would show my private picture, even for a split second before I find the right folder.

Is there an app that only displays the pictures in `/sdcard/portfolio`?

Requirements:

- Works on Android.
- Gratis.
- Pressing the launcher icon directly launches the viewing of the right pictures (either as a gallery of thumbnails or as a slideshow, both are OK). No need to navigate folders or otherwise press anything.
- Configuration survives reboots.
- No advertisements when showing the pictures.
- No need to upload the pictures on any cloud.
- Works offline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A Photo Manager** (whose I am the author of) allows you define a [virtual album file](https://github.com/k3b/APhotoManager/wiki/Bookmarks) that contains `path like '/sdcard/portfolio/%'`. This album-file can be launched from any android-filemanager and only shows photos from that folder.

Before you hand over you android device to somebody else you can enable [Extended App Pinning](https://github.com/k3b/APhotoManager/wiki/AppPinning) so the current folder/album cannot be changed.

May be there is an android tool out there that can put a link to the android desktop for

- intent:action=view +
- data is either file://path/to/raoulsArtfiles.album or a compatible content-uri

Then you are nearly done.

Free and open source, available on F-Droid and UpToDown (not Google Play).

Comment: I downloaded it from F-Droid and could not find that "virtual album" feature (feel free to edit your answer to explain how to do). But I created a new "Filter" specifying the path. The great thing is that when the app starts it "remembers" where it was before, so it works for my purpose :-)

Comment: Before I can accept your answer, please edit your answer and add a disclosure note saying that you are the author of that app, thanks :-)

Comment: done: added that i am the author of and updated the outdated documentation. If you have any idea how to make your intended workflow more intuitive let me know.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **[Camera Roll](https://github.com/kollerlukas/Camera-Roll-Android-App)** for this. It allows to create virtual folders, and hide folders. So you could e.g. hide all folders but the one you want to see. *Camera Roll* is available [at F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/app/us.koller.cameraroll) and [in the Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=us.koller.cameraroll). Let's see how it fits your requirements:

- **Works on Android:** sure, and only there (at least currently).
- **Gratis:** More than that, it's open source.
- **No advertisements when showing the pictures:** No ads at all. Can't even (see next bullet points).
- **No need to upload the pictures on any cloud:** That's not even an option with the app (see next bullet point).
- **Works offline:** Definitely. It doesn't even request any network permissions.
- **Configuration survives reboots:** All but a factory-reset I'd say. That should be normal.
- **Pressing the launcher icon directly launches the viewing of the right pictures:** If you hide all other folders, that should be the case. Haven't tried that yet as I always need multiple folders.

I'm using the app even since before it became available at F-Droid (it's still [available in my repo](https://apt.izzysoft.de/fdroid/index/apk/us.koller.cameraroll) as well, for faster updates), and I'm quite happy with it. Being available at F-Droid says there won't be any nasty surprises in the app. Also, support is very good. I can highly recommend it.

Comment: Great but still two drawbacks: 1) Requires two clicks from launcher, one on the icon then one on the only album. 2) When setting up excluding all other folders can take a long time, and whenever a new app you install decides to store pictures in its own folder (Whatsapp, Foodie, etc) then you have to hide it manually.

Comment: Both should be solvable easily. Just open an issue suggesting 1) if there's only a single folder, jump into it directly and 2) additional to "black-listing" folders (exclude specified folders, as it's done currently), have a "white-listing" option (only show white-listed folders). Lukas usually is fast to respond and implement things if they sound useful/reasonable – which I'd expect him counting this one as.

Comment: https://github.com/kollerlukas/Camera-Roll-Android-App/issues/142 https://github.com/kollerlukas/Camera-Roll-Android-App/issues/206 :-)

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Already got a notification (I'm watching that repo) and gave both a thumbs-up :-)

Answer (score 0):

[QuickPic](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alensw.PicFolder) can be configured to only show/scan certain folders, it can certainly be set to display only one desired folder. (Not sure if it can display those directly without a click first)

It doesn't display ads, works offline and cloud features are present but fully optional as far as I can tell.

**Edit: As users mention in the comments Quickpick has been bought by a untrustworthy company known for shady activities and business practices. While I haven't noticed anything suspicious it is probably best to look for other alternatives.**

Comment: Note that QuickPic has been bought by Cheetah Mobile a while ago – a company that seems not trustable but rather known for shady actions. I wouldn't use any of their apps for security reasons alone (especially not their "CM Security" app which was even caught surfing pr0n in the background).

Comment: Damn! Thanks for the heads-up, wasn't aware of that. Guess it is time to find an alternative. Thanks for the warning, answer updated

Comment: If you look for yourself, check my answer (Camera Roll). Actively maintained. Quite good already, and getting better with each release. Might not yet have all the features of QuickPic, but that might not even be wanted/needed ;)

Comment: Sounds like a decent alternative, gonna give it a try, had already upvoted your answer and wishlisted the app.

Comment: Seems like the app was finally taken down.